# Translating from Javascript to Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm trying to translate the below JS code into Ruby. I'm not looking for a solution, but could someone let me know what concepts I should take from Ruby to translate? Just need a place to start. Code here:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
if (x%3 === 0 || x%5 === 0) {
    sum += x;
  }
} 
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Why are you translating from JS to Ruby? This question is a little vague, since you are asking not for an answer, but a guide. Please put some context as why you are doing this.

Comment: I'm translating for The Odin Project. After I posted another question I realized I don't have as firm a grasp on Ruby as I would like to, in order to give this my best effort before posting. So I've been reading more on Ruby syntax and will repost for part two once I can make a better stab at this.

Comment: Also part one was answered correctly below by Mike H-R -- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum = 0
for x in 0..1000
  if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0
    sum += x
  end
end
puts sum
```

but I'd just do

```
puts (0..1000).inject {|acc, x| if x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0; acc += x; end; acc}
```

Check out this for ruby syntax http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/ruby/ and see here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject for information on inject. (it is called fold in most other languages.)

Comment: Edited to fix mistake.

Comment: You shouldn't use `or` in expressions

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're right, fixed in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your ECMAScript code is equivalent to the following much more simple version:

```
console.log(Array.from({length: 1000}, (_, i) => i).
    filter(n => n%3 === 0 || n%5 === 0).
    reduce((acc, n) => acc + n));
```

And that's also exactly how one would write it in Ruby:

```ruby
puts (0...1000).select {|n| (n%3).zero? || (n%5).zero? }.inject(:+)
# => 233168
```

Comment: Much simpler, you say? I'm gonna disagree with you here. :)

Comment: Concise, perhaps, but simpler? Yeah, I'm with Sergio here.